# Mention user on description Microsoft Azure DevOps API

Tags: html, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm Using Azure devops [API to get the description of a Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and then take that description and paste it into another workitem using [update api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

This is an example of the description that i copy
[image]

Take a look at the **@Susan mention **at the very bottom, this is how it looks on HTML:
[image]

My question here is if there is an API to bring the whole description formatted, because this is what i get as description when i use the [GET API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)
[image]

> "description": "**Summary:**\nSome modifications to fix an issue in
> the **** DPIDs startup code. \n\n**Before:**\nThe PID stream startup
> function is called continously when the TCM is not
> responding.\n\n**Now:**\nThe PID stream startup is only executed one
> time.\n\n**To Test:**\nUse the next ECU Emulator
> branch:\n*********\nEnable the *******vehicle and disable the TCM
> module. Run the ECU Emulator. Run the Auto Agent. Open the mobile app.
> Check in the serial output that The DPIDs are started only
> once.\n\n@<6D4D**********297> Pulled down on 8/12/2020, no more
> looping PID stream startup without TCM. Looks good.",

it would also be nice to know how to attach by this way an image, when i get the description it shows like this: ! [ image (2).png ](https://dev.azu re.com/****/*** /_apis/git/repositories/ac324630-b697-4990-ac7a-cb82443762d2/pullRequests/390/attachments/image%20(2).png)**

Answer (score 1):

API can only get data, it's not able to get the page style. You may add the link to access the page directly.